# Can Selections on Cartesian Products be re-written as Theta Joins.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, relational-algebra

I have read it somewhere in article on query optimization that instead applying selections on cartesion product, it is better to use selection theta joins.
So basically if we have 2 employee tables with age as column then

```
select name from A inner join B on A.age>B.age
```

is faster than

```
select name from A,B where A.age>B.age
```

But we all know that first query is equivalent or has same meaning as query 2. Then why it is said that applying selections on theta join is faster than applying select on cartesion product
I am trying to learn query optimization. And I read following statement

```
Selection(E1 *E2)= E1(theta join operator)E2
```

kindly read point 4 of this article--- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/query-optimization-in-relational-algebra/

What is the difference between the 2 queries in terms of performance?

Comment: We can't tell you why someone wrote something. What exactly is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question, in what context?

Comment: Don't expect us to read some other pages & wonder what is relevant & why, posts should be self-contained, give credit when quoting. [ask] [Help] PS SQL <> relational algebra, INNER JOIN <> theta-join.

Comment: The reasons for preferring the ANSI 92 syntax IMO are (a) When join predicates are in the `ON` clause less likely to forget one and cause an inadvertent cross join (b) easier to follow (c) unless all your joins are inner you will end up mixing syntaxes anyway (and have to deal with confusing precedence of comma operator).  You've tagged SQL Server. The query optimiser will push predicates down with both so it isn't actually doing a cross join then filtering afterwards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45984255/3404097 https://stackoverflow.com/q/44917/3404097 etc etc.

Comment: This is a faq. Re (re)search success: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search was poor & literal but recently improved, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first time I have heard the term "Theta Join". Database developers simply call these inner joins. Your first query

```
select name from A inner join B on A.age > B.age
```

shows an inner join. Your second query

```
select name from A,B where A.age > B.age
```

also shows an inner join, only with deprecated syntax. Before explicit joins (`[INNER] JOIN`, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`) etc. got introduced in the SQL standard in 1992, we just listed the tables comma-separated in the `FROM` clause and used the `WHERE` clause to state the join criteria. While this old syntax still works, it is looked upon with disdain if you still use it.

The following is also an inner join:

```
select name from A cross join B where A.age > B.age
```

Only, it is a hidden (or better: obfuscated) inner join. The developer makes it look like a cross join of the tables and then adds the join criteria later. This is syntactically correct, but semantically it isn't. So, we shouldn't write such queries.

To the DBMS is should make no difference, if you write query #1, #2 or #3. It is all the same query in the end. It would speak against the DBMS, didn't it recognize this and come up with the same execution plan for all these queries. The article mentioning that query #1 is faster than query #2 is either wrong or is talking about some particular DBMS and probably even a particular version of that DBMS then.

Maybe still, the article didn't want to talk about how to write queries, but how to process them. If a DBMS would always build a cartesian product and only then filter the data, it might often be slow. It is usually better to filter early and work with smaller data sets.

Comment: I didn't downvote but that syntax is not deprecated. What was deprecated was proprietary outer join syntax

Comment: @Martin Smith: Well, deprecated in a sense that this is considered out-dated and should rather not be used in new queries. It was used in the 1980s, but then a better syntax that is less prone to errors got introduced in 1992, and this is what we use today.

Comment: I'd argue that old join syntax was deprecated while outer join syntax was removed altogether. deprecated means it shouldn't be used

Comment: You'd be conflating "deprecated" with "discouraged" then. Deprecation has a specific meaning https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver16 - I have noticed in academic papers the ANSI 89 syntax is still going strong. Also the comma separated syntax is actually required for graph tables. It doesn't accept `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: The optimizer isn't perfect. SQL Server 2022 has 439 transformation rules in `sys.dm_exec_query_transformation_stats` - it simply isn't viable for it to evaluate every possible permutation in any moderately complex query - and this isn't every possible transformation that might exist either.

Comment: @raspi: As database developers we strive to write queries that are as readable and thus as maintainable as possible. Usually the DBMS will find a good execution plan. It is a very, very rare thing that we'll tweak our queries, because the database optimizer has problems with our query. The means to get queries faster is usually outside of the queries; typically we'll just provide appropriate indexes. Sometimes we may partition a table.

Comment: theta join is a litterary concept in relational algebrae to call joins made of anything else that equi or natural join (<>, >, <, subqueries... in the ON predicate). Of course, in the demand, it is not appropriate...

Answer (score 1):

In a perfect world there will be no differences in terms of performances between those two queries, because the algrebizer part of the query engine, rewrite your query by separating the different operations into elementary operations of relational algebra. However, the WHERE clause should be a simple filter and not a match of information coming from different tables, which, of course, is a disguised form of join.

In other words your request:

```
select name from A,B where A.age > B.age
```

Starts by being rewritten in relational algebra in the form:

```
select name from A inner join B on A.age > B.age
```

Because a join and a cartesian products are two different operations in terms of relational algebrae...

It is from there that the optimizer will try different strategies to find the shortest execution path.

It therefore follows that, as it is ultimately the same query in terms of "root", the optimization will be strictly identical...

However, as the devil is in the details and as the implementation of an RDBMS is in the physical domain, and as SQL Server, even if it is equipped with one of the best optimizers there are, there are limits. In particular, the time to find an optimal execution plan is an operation which must imperatively be completed “before a certain time”. Then the query excution plan resulting could be not paefectly optimal, but sufficiently good to be used..

Then when your write your query into an appropriate syntax, you will help the optimizer to spend more time to do a better job...

The role of the developer should be to apply good practices... Which is rarely the case, because the set world of relational databases is often ignored by developers who think iteratively...

For example, functions in queries should only be used when there is no other solution. However, often a function can be replaced by a call to a table. For example, date calculations, and generally all date functions, gain performance by being replaced by a calendar table (the famous "tally" tables).